# Testing Python method against 2

Tags: python

1st please pardon the title I didn't know what else to title this. I am trying to test 2 cases. But when I fix it for one it breaks the other. The following method:
singleline_diff_format(line1, line2, idx)

Should return:

```
^
a
```

But instead returns the empty string.

For the case:

`singleline_diff_format('','a,0)`

It correctly returns the empty string for the following case: `singleline_diff_format('abcdefg', 'abc', 5)` because the index 5 is larger than the smaller string. How can I make it so it prints the correct output for both cases? Thank you.

Here is the complete method:

```
def singleline_diff_format(line1, line2, idx):
    """
    Inputs:
      line1 - first single line string
      line2 - second single line string
      idx   - index at which to indicate difference
    Output:
      Returns a three line formatted string showing the location
      of the first difference between line1 and line2.

      If either input line contains a newline or carriage return,
      then returns an empty string.

      If idx is not a valid index, then returns an empty string.
    """
    if "\n" in line1 or "\n" in line2:
        return ""
    if idx < 0:
        return ""
    if len(line1) < len(line2):
        if idx >= len(line1):
            return ""
    if len(line2) < len(line1):
        if idx >= len(line2):
            return ""

    return line1 + "\n" + "="*idx + "^" + "\n" + line2 + "\n"
```

Comment: the two cases `if len(line1) < len(line2):` can be written `if idx >= min(len(line1), len(line2)):`
min/max the most underrated builtins :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because in:

```
if len(line1) < len(line2):
    if idx >= len(line1):
        return ""
```

The following things are true:

```
len(line1) = 0
len(line2) = 1
idx = 0
```

Which reduces to:

```
if 0 < 1:
    if 0 >= 0:
        return ""
```

You can fix this by changing the `>=` to just `>`:

```
if len(line1) < len(line2):
    if idx > len(line1):
        return ""
```

Comment: Thank you Nathan! That was it.

Answer (score 1):

Your function - after correcting - would be logically equivalent to:

```
def singleline_diff_format(s1, s2, idx):
    # trimming of endings from white spaces
    s1, s2 = s1.strip(), s2.strip()
    if (idx > len(s1) or idx > len(s2) or s1 == '' or s2 == ''):
        return ""
    else: 
        return s1 + "\n" + "=" * idx + "^\n" + s2 + "\n"
```

Test by putting `print()` around it:

```
print(singleline_diff_format("abcdfeg", "abdcg", 2))
```

Output:

```
abcdfeg
==^
abdcg
```